# "trade" for "business deal; transaction" in North American vernacular

Tags: american-english, word-usage, north-american-english, vernacular, disambiguities

Harrap's New Shorter English-French Dictionary, Ed. 1982, states,

***trade***

> [...]
>
> **2.** (*b*) *NAm* (i) transaction (commerciale); (ii) clientèle *f* (d'une maison); **carriage trade**, grosse clientèle.
>
> [...]

Now, looking up "transaction" in the French-English section of the dictionary, here's what it says:

***transaction***

> *n.f.* **1.** (*a*) *Com:* transaction; *pl.* dealings, deals.
>
> [...]

Random House Webster's College Dictionary, Ed. 1991, supports that "transaction" sense of "trade."

***trade***

> [...]
>
> 2. [a purchase or sale; business deal or transaction](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/trade).
>
> [...]

My question is, is this usage of "trade" actually restricted to North American vernacular or has it since spread into other regions of the English speaking world?

In addition, can "trade" work fine as a substitute for "business transaction" in all senses of "a purchase or sale; business deal or transaction"?

Please, compare:

> *carriage trade: Wealthy, well-to-do, or upper-class customers receiving special treatment or the **transactions** conducted with them, as distinguished from the working class. Businesses catering to these customers sell high-end, or high-priced, goods and services and tend to offer amenities in their shops not ordinarily found in standard retailers or service providers. The term originally applied to rich theater patrons or store clients who traveled in private carriages.*

-and-

> *carriage trade: Wealthy, well-to-do, or upper-class customers receiving special treatment or the **trades** conducted with them, as distinguished from the working class. Businesses catering to these customers sell high-end, or high-priced, goods and services and tend to offer amenities in their shops not ordinarily found in standard retailers or service providers. The term originally applied to rich theater patrons or store clients who traveled in private carriages.*

Source: [Business Dictionary](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/carriage-trade.html#ixzz3zlIjMera)

Comment: In financial context they are  synonyms. The only slight difference I percieve it that transaction is probably more used in  'settlement' contexts while trade is more used in active "buying and selling" activities.

Comment: Note that ***deal*** is also used as a synonym of trade:  - A  business transaction: struck a deal to buy a car dealership. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deal

Comment: In your example only transaction in correct, paying with a credit cart is not a financial activity, but just consumer spending, you are just paying.

Comment: @Josh61 Right. Then, by analogy with "struck a deal to buy a car dealership," can one say, "struck a trade to buy a car dealership"?

Comment: @Josh61 Sure, but it still is a business transaction between two parties, i.e. the merchant and the customer.

Comment: I don't think so, "struck a deal" is idiomatic. Note that *transaction and trade* are synonyms in professional buying and selling activities where prices changes quickly and there may be a degree of interaction before the deal is closed. Trade suggest a number of similar transactions. It may be used also for everyday purchases when you get a good price for instance.

Comment: @Josh61 Then, could you give some example sentences of "trade" used in the sense "business deal; transaction"?

Comment: All buying and selling activities in all markets ( stocks,  commodities, financial derivatives for instances) are trades or transactions.

Comment: I think you should see Investopedia also for those terms: http://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/trade.asp

Comment: @MarkHubbard That sense of "trade" isn't what we're talking about. That sense refers to a collection of business activities. His sentence is a tautology, since he's using trade to mean commerce.

Comment: @Barmar- Exactly. Apparently humor doesn't "scan" well in comments. Sorry.

Comment: @Elian- I think you need be more specific if you want an answer. Are you interested mainly in the meaning and usage of  transaction/trade as  in your last example? I'd use neither of them in those sentences.

Comment: @Josh61 Actually, I'd like to get examples (preferably sourced ones) of "trade" being used in the sense "a purchase or sale; business deal or transaction."

Comment: Here are same examples you can check: "trades executed" https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=trades+executed&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctrades%20executed%3B%2Cc0 - "a trade with" - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+trade+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20trade%20with%3B%2Cc0 -

Comment: Elian loves to ask questions that require a grand knowledge of global English usage practices. I think there are a slim number of people in this forum who can legitimately answer your embedded question, sir. In addition, I don't think the meanings are as synonymous as your hand-picked definitions might lead one to believe (in agreement with @JimB in his answer). The use of the term 'trade' meaning 'commerce' is not uncommon; but the use of the term 'trade' meaning 'transaction' is almost unheard of (speaking as a North American).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can "trade" work fine as a substitute for "business transaction" in
>   all senses of "a purchase or sale; business deal or transaction"?

No.

> carriage trade: Wealthy, well-to-do, or upper-class customers
>   receiving special treatment or the transactions conducted with them,

In your examples, “transactions” is correct. If you use “trades” that suggests bartering in this context.

If you are talking specifically about one person dealing with one person, then “trade” suggests bartering, while “transaction” suggests that one person is paying cash and receiving a good or service in return. “Transaction” is very specific.

However, more broadly, you can talk about ”the sex trade,” “stock trading,” or “trade deals” and trade still works. Money is just one of the things being traded.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. In fact, Usage of the word *trade* in the sense of *transaction* is much more restricted in the North American vernacular than your dictionary suggests. (I am a native English speaker from the US.) It is typically limited to cases where things are bartered rather than simply sold or purchased, such as, "I'll trade you my antique clock for your bicycle," or with respect to the purchase or sale of stocks or commodities. The word would never be used the way you used it in your example.

Comment: No, “trade” can also refer to deals where money changes hands. The “sex trade,” “stock trading,” “trade deals.”

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking the phrase out and simply saying "customers receiving special treatment, as distinguished from the working class."